# "Community" user shouldn't get badges

Tags: bug, status-completed

The community user (a fake "system" account) has gotten the silver [deputy badge](https://photo.stackexchange.com/badges/73/deputy), as well as a few others. This [dilutes the value of the badge](http://data.stackexchange.com/photography/s/1306/badges-to-aspire-to) and should be prevented. (It also has a few copper badges that really should go too.)

Comment: But he puts in such long hours, diligent and steadfast in his work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the next build Community will not be able to earn badges.  Cleanup of the badges it earned in the past will be completed after the build...since they would just be re-granted until a new build is pushed to correct the granting behavior.

Comment: Cool, thanks. It's not urgent or anything. :)